# How to copy/include external file in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

My project depends on react and mxGraph, and i am using webpack as bundle tool. Currently i am building react using webpack and manually including 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mxGraph/mxClient.js"></script>`

in index.html file. Now i want to  concat/add mxClient.js file content to bundle.js file generated by webpack.

index.js

```
var React = require('react'),
    ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

window.React = React;
window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
```

this generates bundle.js file with react deps to this i want to add/append mxClient.js content to bundle.js via webpack

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is in the comments: http://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html

Comment: Is your purpose to add a second script tag to the page?  Or to concatinate this file to the end of bundle.js?  Or to get your `require('./path/to/mxClient');` call inside your code to resolve the reference?  The answer to each is quite different.

Comment: concatinate this file to the end of bundle.js

Comment: Easiest way to do this is get [gulp](gulpjs.com) to run webpack, and then run a second task that concatenates bundle with mxClient.js, writing a new file.  It'll probably be much, much easier to just add a second script tag to the page though.

Comment: ok, thought there is an simpler way using webpack. yeah its easier to add second script tag to html file but i have 4 more js files and i want to send only one http request on load.

Comment: then gulp is definitely your friend.